# Sharepoint 2013 + IE 10 version I have found issue in multi line column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

### **my question is about sharepoint strange behavior in IE versions. Issue in IE10 version and sharepoint description column**

> - Type of information in this Column : Multiple lines of text
> - Specify the type of text to allow: Rich text (Bold, italics, text    alignment, hyperlinks)

when am trying to change the font style of selected sentence in description column. The selected font style is not applied for the sentence and getting error in browser console

[image: IE Version 10].

If i am working on IE8 version it is working fine without an error and I have added screen shot also please check for more understanding this issue.

[image: IE Version 8]

I need solution for this strange behavior. It should work in IE 10 version or If it is known issue please share the official Blogs/docs.

Comment: it would be helpful if you share the code you are using

Comment: Did you try compability view?

Comment: Hi Tiago Duarte, Am not using any code to develop this. It is SharePoint out of box component :Description column - specific type is Rich text (Bold, italics, text alignment, hyperlinks).

Comment: Hi Newbie,  I have checked Description column in IE 8 version. there working fine but our system requirement is compatible mode should be IE 10.